# Providing robust consistency checks for collection of classes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

To give some background on what I am doing:

I have a program that allows a user to modify and create a general calibration.  Inside this calibration includes groups.  Groups differ by the type of analysis they perform.  These groups also included spectral sets with each set containing data for only one molecule. Inside these sets also includes spectral data at varying concentrations.  Each spectra data is a discrete set of data which is specified by its resolution (x-axis space between each point) and its spectral range (x axis range).

One of the main aspects of building these calibration files is to keep the resolution and spectral range consistent in all spectral data in each set.  This means that spectral data cannot be added unless it matches the spectral data of the rest. Also, if the user deletes all spectral data the resolution and range is reset allowing Spectra data of any range or resolution to be added to the calibration.

The question is:  How can I provided an effective way to prevent adding spectral data to the calibration that doesn't match the current resolution and spectral range???

Below is a general description of a calibration class.  This is a very general description and contains the only info needed to explain what I am trying to do.

```
class calibration
{
    List<Group> groups;
}


class Group
{
    List<SpectralSet> sets;
}

class SpectralSet
{
    List<SpectraData> spectras;
}

class SpectraData
{
    double firstXPoint;
    double lastXPoint;
    double resolution;
    double[] Ypoints; 
}
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Check the edit I made.

Comment: @Berigan, what stops you (or your code) from checking whether a SpectraData matches the criteria you told about (*if* statements?), and only add them to SpectraData.spectras if the criteria are satisfied...?

Comment: 2 questions: 1. What exactly is "spectral range" in terms of the properties on `SpectraData`. And which `SpectraData` need to match? Is it all `SpectraData` in a single set? Or all `SpectraData` in all `SpectralSet`s in a single `Group`? Or all `SpectraData` in all `SpectralSet`s across all `Group`s?

Comment: In the question I specified range to be x-axis range. The highest x value and lowest x avlue defines the range in this context.  Any spectradata being added to any set in any group must match the spectradata that is already in there that is located in any group in any set.  The first spectradata added to any set in any group pretty much defines the requirements for the format of any spectradata to be added next. ALso, if the last spectradata is removed, then of course, the spectral requirements are freed.

Comment: @Bergian As I allude to in my answer, you make life unnecessarily difficult by saying you must be able to automatically clear the requirements when all the groups are emptied. Why not control that manually? It's a little extra work at the top level but makes everything else so much easier

Comment: @Berigan Updated the answer with a version which does do that though, in case it's a firm requirement for some reason I'm not aware of

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could apply all sorts of fancy design patterns to enforce the rules you mention.

However, for the sake of simplicity, I would just encapsulate the logic in the `calibration` class with an `AddGroup` method which validates the added `group` conforms to the calibration's requirements. Similarly, I would create an `AddSpectralSet` method to the `group` class as a gate keeper into the `sets` collection.

At that point, depending on how often these things change, I would think about exposing the `groups` collection and `sets` collection as `ReadOnlyCollection` to ensure code doesn't try to add items without using the prescribed methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good ideas. Although, groups and spectral sets can be added blank with no format specifications.  It boils down to when the spectra data is added to the sets once they have been added.  The first spectra data in any set defines the resolution and range.  Any after that must conform to that in any set in any group.  Also, when all spectra data in every set in every group has been removed, the spectral range and resolution requirements are left open or reset.  Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will probably vary a bit, but here's an outline of how you could achieve this. You need to do the following:

- Only expose immutable public collection properties, along with an `Add` method, so that you can do your own validation.

For example, you don't want to do:

```
class Group
{
    public List<SpectralSet> sets;
}
```

Because then anyone can just do `myGroup.sets.Add(mySet)`, without you getting a chance to do any validation on the set. One common pattern to achieve this is as follows:

```
class Group
{
    private List<SpectralSet> _sets;
    public IEnumerable<SpectralSet> Sets { get { return _sets; } }

    public void Add(SpectralSet set)
    {
        //Do validation here, throw an exception or whatever you want to do if the set isn't valid
        _sets.Add(set);
    }

    //Have a similar Remove method
}
```

- Store the criteria that the data must match

I'm not quite sure what a spectral range is, so I'll just use the resolution as an example. You can extend this to whatever the range criteria is simply. There's at least three possible ways you could do this:

1. When you construct a class, pass it the resolution that it's allowed in the constructor, and make this immutable.
2. When adding and removing, update the allowed resolution as necessary.
3. Don't store the resolution explicitly, calculate it every time you add or remove.

Out of those, option 1 is by far the simplest. Life is always much easier when you can keep things as immutable as possible. So you'd do something like:

```
class Group
{
    private List<SpectralSet> _sets;
    public IEnumerable<SpectralSet> Sets { get { return _sets; } }
    public readonly double Resolution;

    public Group(double resolution)
    {
        Resolution = resolution;
    }

    public void Add(SpectralSet set)
    {
        if(set.Resolution != resolution)
            //Throw an Exception here, or however you want to handle invalid data
        _sets.Add(set);
    }

    //Have a similar Remove method
}
```

Following this example, each of the classes you included would need a `Resolution` parameter with the same kind of logic, just checking the `Resolution` of any direct child you tried to add. Likewise with whatever you use for spectral range.

You also want to be able to change the resolution allowed if all data is cleared. The simplest way to do this is just create new objects whenever the data is cleared, rather than just clearing out the collections in existing objects.

- Make `SpectraData` immutable

All this is useless if you can get a `SpectraData` out of one of the carefully gated collections and change it arbitrarily. Make anything that needs to be validated immutable, only allowing it to be set on construction. If you have a requirement not to do that, you need to think very carefully about how you will allow it to be changed.

Comment: This is good, but I can't set the resolution to null even if there is no spectradata in an arbitrary set. The consistency must be across all spectraData in all Sets in all Groups, not just all sets within a group.

Comment: @Berigan Hm, how much of an issue is performance? Is iterating over these collections a lot going to be an intolerable performance hit?